# RASA Story w/ Slots

Tags: entities, rasa-nlu, slots, rasa-core

Can someone clarify for me with Rasa stories involving slots:

```
## story with email
* intent_request_email
    - utter_request_email
* inform_email {"email":"example@example.com"}
    - slot {"email":"example@example.com"}
    - utter_thanks
```

In the above, does `example@example.com` act as a placeholder for **any email address** (ie, will work equally for `john.smith@somedomain.com`), or is this effectively limiting this story to the case when the email provided is exactly `example@example.com`

Now consider the case below, for entities that are floats:

```
## story with numeric
* intent_want_to_buy
    - utter_request_budget
* inform_budget {"amount":100}
    - slot {"amount":100}
    - utter_thanks
```

Does the `100` act as a placeholder for **any amount that is provided** (ie 200, 300, 65.95), or, is it actually saying that this story is to be applied only when and only if the user states their budget is exactly $100.00.

With the above in mind, how does one control a story to be executed when the slot has NOT been set, vs a path to be taken when the slot has been filled/provided.

The documentation is rather lacking in these kinds of basics, which are obvious once known, but are not so obvious for someone new to Rasa.

Comment: I came here looking for
how does one control a story to be executed when the slot has NOT been set, vs a path to be taken when the slot has been filled/provided

Answer (score 2):

The specific entity values in the stories are placeholders only and do not effect the story line.

Only in the nlu training data the annotated entity values have an effect, helping intent classification.